# Massload with Open_all in JSTree and Lazy Loading

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using JSTree in my application.

I have very huge data to be displayed in JSTree.

I have around 200 000 nodes to be displayed.

I provided search functionality to user. Upon search I am clearing previous instance of jstree and creating new instance with required data.

On Loaded event which is fired when "Root" node is loaded I am calling open_all() method to open all nodes,

I have huge data and I am using lazy loading. So for example in one case I have 20K nodes inside one node. So it makes 20K ajax request which ultimately leads to "ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES".

**How can I integrate massload functionality over here with open_all()?**

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special that you need to do - provided `massload` is configured in your instance it will intercept the call that happens after the search and load needed nodes in a single batch. This will however not work for `open_all` as jstree does not know the IDs in advance.

But since you are creating a new instance, and then invoking `open_all` on it - why do you even add lazy loading to that instance? You are loading all the nodes anyway - simple return the whole structure when the request for the root comes in.